# ffmpeg video editing command in milliseconds timestamp

Tags: ffmpeg, command, html5-video, milliseconds

I am editing a video with `ffmpeg` where I have to keep in view the timestamp further deep from seconds to milliseconds. I know such command : `ffmpeg -i a.ogg -ss 00:01:02 -to 00:01:03 -c copy x2.ogg`. This uses seconds, but I want down to milliseconds.

Answer (score 135, accepted):

you can try:

```
ffmpeg -i a.ogg -ss 00:01:02.500 -t 00:01:03.250 -c copy x2.ogg
```

Timestamps need to be in HH:MM:SS.xxx format for advanced precision (where xxx are milliseconds).

Let me know if it works.

Comment: this is weird.  i'm requesting 13 frames of video but it's only saying it copied 3!

Answer (score 17):

Time duration can be present two format. (**FFmpeg 4.3** or newer)

**Format 1 :**

```
[-][HH:]MM:SS[.m...]
```

*or*

**Format 2 :**

```
[-]S+[.m...][s|ms|us]
```

**Format 1 samples**

```
01:20:10        1 hour 20 minute 10 seconds
04:03           4 minutes 3 seconds
07:02:05.100    7 hours 2 minutes 5 seconds 100 miliseconds
```

**Format 2 samples**

```
120             120 seconds
120.2           120.2 seconds or 120 seconds 200 miliseconds
1200ms          1200 milliseconds
1300us          1300 microseconds
```

I never rely on decimals. If possible, use always format2 (-ss '120534ms').

```
ffmpeg -i a.ogg -ss '100ms' -t '600ms' -c copy x2.ogg
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be:

```
ffmpeg -i a.ogg -ss 100ms -t 600ms -c copy x2.ogg
```

not

```
ffmpeg -i a.ogg -ss '100ms' -t '600ms' -c copy x2.ogg
```