# ffmpeg being inprecise when trimming mp3 files

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, mp3

I want to use ffmpeg to trim some mp3s without re-encoding. The command I used was
`ffmpeg -i "inputfile.mp3" -t 00:00:12.414 -c copy out.mp3`
However, out.mp3 has a length of 12.460s, and when I load the file in Audacity I can see that it was cut at the wrong spot, and not at 12.414s.

Why is this? I googled a bit and tried some other commands like `ffmpeg -i "inputfile.mp3" -ss 0 -to 00:00:12.414 -c copy out.mp3` (which interestingly results in a different length of 12.434s) but could never get the milliseconds to be cut right.

[image]

[image]

PS. I wasn't sure whether SO was the right place to ask since it isn't technically programming related, however most of the stuff  I found on ffmpeg for trimming audio files were stackoverflow questions, e. g. [ffmpeg trimming videos with millisecond precision](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23171937/ffmpeg-video-editing-command-in-milliseconds-timestamp)

Comment: I have the same problem did you ever find a solution to trim more precisely?

Comment: @EdmundRojas No. Unfortunately, it doesn't seem possible to trim lossy audio with high precision. See also Brad's answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't trim MP3 (nor most lossy codec output) with that level of precision.  An MP3 frame or so of padding is added during encoding.  (See also:  https://wiki.hydrogenaud.io/index.php?title=Gapless, and all the hacks required to make this work.)

If you need precision timing, use something uncompressed like PCM in WAV, or a lossless compression like FLAC.

Comment: Very interesting answer, may i ask what about with mpeg2 ts (mp2). Might trim with total precision with this format??

Answer (score 0):

**On Linux** you can use **[mp3splt](http://mp3splt.sourceforge.net/mp3splt_page/about.php)**:

> mp3splt -f mp3file.mp3 **from**  **to** -o **output file format**

Example:

> mp3splt -f "/home/audio folder/test.mp3" 0.11.89  3.25.48 -o @f_trimmed
> this will create a "/home/audio folder/test_trimmed.mp3"

For more info to the parameters, check the mp3splt man page [here](http://mp3splt.sourceforge.net/mp3splt_page/documentation/man.html)

---

**On Windows** you can use **[mp3DirectCut](https://mpesch3.de/)**

mp3DirectCut has a GUI, but it also have command line support