# Generete one second of black video and relative silence audio

Tags: ffmpeg

How can I generate a black mp4 video with relative silent audio track with ffmpeg, I need the audio and video tracks to correspond to the duration of 1 second

```
ffmpeg -f lavfi -i color=c=black:s=1920x1080:r=24/1 -c:v h264 -f lavfi -i anullsrc=cl=stereo:r=44100 -video_track_timescale 90k -c:a mp3 -b:a 320k -ar 44100 -ac 2 -t 3 out.mp4
```

VIDEO FORMAT CONTAINER DURATION: 3.026000

VIDEO STREAM DURATION: 3.000000

how can i match these durations?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: According the [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54153364/ffmpeg-being-inprecise-when-trimming-mp3-files) post it looks like `mp3` codec doesn't support that level of precision. Just for testing, with `flac` codec audio duration is precise: `ffmpeg -f lavfi -i color=c=black:s=1920x1080:r=24/1 -c:v h264 -f lavfi -i anullsrc=cl=stereo:r=44100 -video_track_timescale 90k -c:a flac -strict -2 -b:a 320k -ar 44100 -ac 2 -t 3 out.mp4`

Comment: Thanks @Rotem very interesting but i need mp3 or aac precise format container duration to append this silence after cancatenation process (concat filter), i understand that for some reason, ffmpeg creates an additional initial audio packet,
> marked with
> side_data_type=Skip Samples
> skip_samples=1105

Comment: The concat filter keeps the corresponding A/V streams in sync.

Comment: thanks a lot guys, may i ask if m4a also have this temporal inprecision for trim?